# Logical equivalence of a sequence of if else if else clauses

Tags: python, logic, control-flow, equivalence

I am seriously under-slept and I need help in rewriting this small Python piece of logic

```
for _ in range(100):
    if a:
        continue
    elif b:
        continue
    elif c and d:
        continue
    else:
        e()
```

I want to have something like

```
if (some_exprt of a,b,c,d):
    e()
```

What I got is:

```
if not a and  not b and (not c or not d):
   e()
```

but I really can't tell if this is correct or not, am I right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Try thinking of it from the "bottom up". "Execute e() if neither a or b or c and d is true"

Comment: You can use [De_Morgan's_laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to transform your answer to the ones that @Martijn gives

Comment: @InbarRose looping and skipping over iterations that are unfaourable

Comment: Simple conditions are better than complex ones, and `continue` is fine too (see e.g. http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#use-early-exits-and-continue-to-simplify-code). Just replace `elif`s with `if`s and you're done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with under what conditions the `else` branch would *not* match. It'd be one of `a`, or `b`, or `c and d`, so you would need to use `or` and `not` here to express when the `else` branch of your original code would be picked:

```
if not (a or b or (c and d)):
    e()
```

You could then bring the `not` into the parenthesis by applying [one of De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), expressing the preceding test more verbosely as:

```
if not a and not b and not (c and d):
    e()
```

which could then be further expanded to:

```
if not a and not b and (not c or not d):
    e()
```

which is what you yourself already expanded to. But I'd find the first version to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

[continue](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) cannot work inside an if statement. So I assume you are running this inside a loop(while or for). Try this:

```
#whatever loop
if not(a or b or (c and d)):
    e()
```

Second approach without a not will be:

```
if a or b or (c and d):
    continue
else:
    e()
```

As M. Martjin Peters explained in the comments, the else block within the second approach is not necessary. You can remove the else and move e() outside the if block. However, in my opinion, an else after an if will make the code more readable.

Second approach can also be written as:

```
if a or b or (c and d):
    continue
e()
```

Comment: I am, I'll expand the context

Comment: I think we can assume here that the `if` statement was the only code in the loop.

Comment: That's the safe assumption :-) I just wanted to clarify to OP that continue cannot be used within a if block, in case he is trying :-)

Comment: If you are continuing *anyway* you can just drop the `else` and dedent the `e()` call. `if a or b or (c and d): continue` *newline* `e()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's right. Thanks. I will update the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not any((a, b, (c and d))):
    e()
```

Comment: This would evaluate `a`, `b` and `c` (and perhaps `d`) before calling `any()`. This will *not* short-circuit when `a` evaluates to a false value. That could be important.